MicroSoft auth2 error:unauthorized_client
When I tried to access Microsoft auth2 third-party login, the first step :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=
e02d3426-4764-4d6b-aac5-7454652503f7&redirect_uri=https://www.rxew.cc/oauth/microsoft&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile

reported the following error:

unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

My configuration is：
Google and Bing checked and also changed the client ID, but it still reports an error. This is my first time doing it, could you please advise me where it hasn't been set up yet?

Have you added any Redirect URIs yet?

yes .redirect_uri=https://www.rxew.cc/oauth/microsoft

I can't tell if you are referring to the parameter you put into the authorization dialog URL now, or if you actually entered this in your app configuration dashboard.

I put into the authorization dialog URL.

You need to add it in your app setup as well ... that's why there's a link, "Add a Redirect URI".
